# MYSQL: SELECT latest date per group per group

Tags: mysql, select

I have a brainteaser in this one.
I already searched around but everything I find works finding the latest for 1 group. Not a group in a group.

I have a table with the following headers:

*ID | vehicle id | type of cleaning | date*

Every ID is unique. There are around 25 different vehicle id's that can be in there for a more than 1 time. There are 3 types of cleaning and there is of course the date.
The idea is that every time a vehicle gets a cleaning this is registered in a new record. example: vehicle 110 is getting an interior cleaning on the 1th of October.
If I then have another interior cleaning of vehicle 110 on the 25th of October a new record is added so we have a database that records all cleanings.

For a quick view of which vehicle has been cleaned for every type of cleaning I need 1 query that gives me an array that tells me the vehicle number, the type and the LATEST date.

I have tried different options and the closest I came with:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM cleanings
GROUP BY vehicle_id, type
ORDER BY vehicle_id ASC, date DESC;
```

This gives the first cleaning date per type per vehicle which mostly is the oldest date.

SAMPLE DATA:

```sql
INSERT INTO `cleanings` (`id`, `vehicle_id`, `employees_id`, `type`, `date`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(1, 15103, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2023-10-06', '2023-10-08 06:44:22', '2023-10-09 18:50:08'),
(2, 15103, 2, 'Buitenkant', '2023-10-08', '2023-10-08 06:44:34', '2023-10-09 18:54:25'),
(3, 15102, 2, 'Buitenkant', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-09 14:15:34', '2023-10-09 18:43:24'),
(4, 15101, 1, 'Buitenkant', '1989-11-10', '2023-10-09 14:22:53', '2023-10-09 17:35:17'),
(5, 15110, 2, 'Buitenkant', '2022-10-19', '2023-10-09 18:49:59', '2023-10-13 14:12:24'),
(6, 15110, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2022-10-18', '2023-10-08 04:44:22', '2023-10-13 14:12:17'),
(7, 15109, 2, 'Binnenkant', '2023-10-08', '2023-10-08 04:44:34', '2023-10-09 18:52:16'),
(8, 15116, 2, 'Binnenkant', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-09 12:15:34', '2023-10-09 18:52:16'),
(9, 15118, 1, 'Binnenkant', '1989-11-10', '2023-10-09 12:22:53', '2023-10-09 18:52:16'),
(10, 15119, 2, 'Binnenkant', '2023-10-19', '2023-10-09 16:49:59', '2023-10-09 18:52:16'),
(11, 15101, 1, 'Saniswiss', '2023-10-06', '2023-10-08 04:44:22', '2023-10-13 08:16:48'),
(12, 15103, 2, 'Saniswiss', '2023-10-08', '2023-10-08 04:44:34', '2023-10-09 18:52:59'),
(13, 15116, 2, 'Saniswiss', '2023-10-03', '2023-10-09 12:15:34', '2023-10-09 18:52:59'),
(14, 15111, 1, 'Saniswiss', '1989-11-10', '2023-10-09 12:22:53', '2023-10-09 18:52:59'),
(15, 15112, 2, 'Saniswiss', '2023-10-19', '2023-10-09 16:49:59', '2023-10-09 18:52:59'),
(16, 15105, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2023-10-09', '2023-10-09 18:58:33', '2023-10-09 18:58:33'),
(17, 15105, 2, 'Binnenkant', '2023-10-06', '2023-10-09 20:38:00', '2023-10-16 22:51:17'),
(18, 15112, 2, 'Binnenkant', '2023-12-12', '2023-10-16 22:51:32', '2023-10-16 22:51:32'),
(19, 15590, 15, 'Saniswiss', '2024-01-01', '2023-10-17 12:35:48', '2023-10-30 21:02:02'),
(21, 15101, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2023-10-20', '2023-10-17 14:46:29', '2023-10-17 14:46:29'),
(29, 15107, 15, 'Buitenkant', '2023-11-24', '2023-11-01 11:34:28', '2023-11-01 11:34:28'),
(30, 15215, 14, 'Saniswiss', '2023-11-20', '2023-11-01 11:35:32', '2023-11-01 11:35:32'),
(31, 15213, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2023-11-01', '2023-11-01 11:35:41', '2023-11-01 11:35:41'),
(32, 15118, 1, 'Binnenkant', '2023-11-02', '2023-11-02 10:02:51', '2023-11-02 10:02:51'),
(33, 15118, 1, 'Binnenkant', '2023-11-02', '2023-11-02 10:03:21', '2023-11-02 10:03:21'),
(34, 15118, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2023-11-02', '2023-11-02 10:05:08', '2023-11-02 10:05:08'),
(35, 15101, 1, 'Buitenkant', '2023-11-02', '2023-11-02 10:55:38', '2023-11-02 10:55:38');
```

SAMPLE RESULT FROM QUERY:

```php
array (size=21)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 4
      'vehicle_id' => int 15101
      'employees_id' => int 1
      'type' => string 'Buitenkant' (length=10)
      'date' => string '1989-11-10' (length=10)
      'created' => string '2023-10-09 16:22:53' (length=19)
      'modified' => string '2023-10-09 19:35:17' (length=19)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 11
      'vehicle_id' => int 15101
      'employees_id' => int 1
      'type' => string 'Saniswiss' (length=9)
      'date' => string '2023-10-06' (length=10)
      'created' => string '2023-10-08 06:44:22' (length=19)
      'modified' => string '2023-10-13 10:16:48' (length=19)
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      'id' => int 3
      'vehicle_id' => int 15102
      'employees_id' => int 2
      'type' => string 'Buitenkant' (length=10)
      'date' => string '2023-10-03' (length=10)
      'created' => string '2023-10-09 16:15:34' (length=19)
      'modified' => string '2023-10-09 20:43:24' (length=19)
```

SAMPLE END RESULT:
[image: Sample result]

Comment: Often people asking questions such as yours include, as text, sample data for their tables and a sample of the desired result. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: This looks like a variant of a common problem - the rows holding the groupwise maximum of a certain column.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html for a summary of different approaches

Comment: @O.Jones Edited with more information

Comment: @RobEyre Edited why this doesn't work. Basically on every "solution" I found it is about the latest date per grouping. My problem is the grouping in a grouping and then the latest date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the `LEFT JOIN` approach from https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html, something along these lines may give you the result you're looking for.  The join conditions mean that for each row we look for another row for the same vehicle and type but a later date.  The `WHERE` clause then enforces the condition that there should be no such matching row (which can only be true if the row is already the latest for the vehicle and type combination)

```
SELECT c1.* 
FROM cleanings c1
LEFT JOIN cleanings c2 ON
  c1.vehicle_id = c2.vehicle_id
  AND c1.type = c2.type
  AND c2.date > c1.date
WHERE c2.ID IS NULL
ORDER BY c1.vehicle_id ASC, c1.date DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It functions as it should.